# Is there any english version [online, PDF] of the following?

Tags: etymology, german, online-resources, references

Is there any english version [online, PDF] of the following?:

```
Mayhofer, Etymologisches    Wörterbuch des Altindoarischen.
```

I had downloaded one but unfortunately it was in German language which is beyond my reach. I will be so much thankful for every help.

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Mayrhofer's first edition (KEWA) has definitions in both German and English. The much improved second edition (EWAia) is in German only. If you are serious about historical linguistics you need to know German.

Both books are protected by copyright, but I suppose that you can find pirated electronic versions on some shady website.